# How to pipe Coredump to a custom application?

Tags: systemd, core-dump

I wrote a simple C application (in core_app.c) to process a coredump:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("/tmp/coretest", "w");
    char input[MAX_INPUT];
    // write a coredump to /tmp/coretest
    if (fp != 0) {
        while (fgets(input, MAX_INPUT, stdin)) {
            fputs(input, fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        perror("[FMon] cannot open file!");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and then I set the core_pattern using a systemd service which contains:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo '| core_app' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern"
```

After a reset the content of the file `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` is correct. But the syslog shows:

```
Jan 01 00:19:52 kernel: Core dump to | core_app pipe failed
```

Anybody knows why the pipe failed?
Thanks

Comment: have you tried full path? is your core_app has "x" bit?

Comment: thanks @user996142! yes, the missing full path was the issue.
Do you know how to deal with the specifier conflict between systemd and coredump. If I type `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo '| /usr/bin/core_app %e %p %c' > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` in the service file, the specifier `%p` and `%c are subtitute to the service name and service path.

Comment: Thats because of https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532499/how-to-escape-a-systemd-specifier-to-pass-to-the-command-in-execstart/40533049#40533049

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel invokes the command declared in `core_pattern` from the process's current directory. This is a direct kernel invocation, so there is no PATH lookup. Therefore `core_app` must be an executable file in the process's current directory.

To invoke a particular `core_app` executable no matter what the process's current directory is, use the full path to `core_app`, e.g.

```
echo '|/usr/local/sbin/core_app' >/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```